# Array within array ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array within an array. I can call a certain object by doing this...

```
array[1][2]
```

I would like to be able to insert a variable instead of one of these values. Maybe something like...

```
array[#{variable1}][#{variable2}]
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Just use `array[variable1][variable2]`. The `#{...}` is for inserting a Ruby value/expression inside a string.

Comment: what do you mean? please provide at least some examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace the numeric literal with the variable:

```
variable1 = 1
variable2 = 2

array[variable1][variable2]
```

Comment: Ok it seems I have a different problem then as this is throwing an error...

Comment: @SamSweeney, Could you show me the code you tried and the full error message?

Comment: :49:in `[]': can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)

Comment: @SamSweeney, If the value of the variable is string, you need to convert it to `Fixnum`: `array[variable1.to_i][variable2.to_i]`

Comment: @xlembouras, If the `array` was not initialized, other error would be thrown: `undefined local variable or method ...`

Answer (score 1):

What you mentioned is known as `string interpolation`, but can only be used in quotes.

For example, say you have a variable defined, `price`

```
price = 80
```

You can say something like this

```
puts "The price is $#{price}"
```

This will translate to `The price is $80`

It's not possible to do that in arrays, but it is possible to substitute values inside

```
a = 7
b = 9
```

`array[a]` will get the 8th value of the array, whereas `array[b]` will get the 10th value of the array.

Hope this helps.